# Is it possible to invert camelcase in liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I split word `'CamelCaseWord'` in liquid to `'Camel Case Word'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With liquid filter available in Jekyll 3.1.x, it's not possible.

But you can create a new [liquid filter plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#liquid-filters).